# RegEx to process and change multiple links in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am having a hard time figuring this out:

I have a string ($data) which contains some links formatted this way:

```
[pagelink]Folder/File[/pagelink]
```

The $data contains multiple of these links.

I need to replace these links with actual html links and I have this code to do it (which works):

```
$data = preg_replace('/\[pagelink\](.*?)\[\/pagelink\]/is','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$data);
```

Now I would like to remove all the "Folder" instances from the part of the link that is showed to the user without actually altering the link itself; in other words if the link is this:

```
[pagelink]Folder/File[/pagelink]
```

I would like it to become this:

```
<a href="Folder/File">File</a>
```

What I tried is this:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\[pagelink\](.*?)\[\/pagelink\]/is','<a href="$1">'.( strstr($1) === false ? $1 : str_replace('/','',strstr($1)) ).'</a>',$data);
```

but I get a bunch of errors so I guess I can't use back references this way.

Could you guys help me out please?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to calculate the replacement dynamically from the match, you must use `preg_replace_callback()`, since variables are evaluated before calling the function (and `$1` is not a real variable, it's a special sequence recognized in replacement strings). But you don't need it in this case, I'll show you in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Revise your regular expression so the folder and file are in separate capture groups.

```
$data = preg_replace('#\[pagelink\](.*?/)?([^/]*?)\[/pagelink\]#is','<a href="$1$2">$2</a>',$data);
```

Capture group `1` gets `Folder/`, capture group `2` gets `File`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that:

```
$data = preg_replace('~\[pagelink](/?(?>[^[/]+/)*([^/[]+))\[/pagelink]~', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like BBCode. PHP has an extension for that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php

One of the comments links to a PHP implementation of the library.

If you need logic to compile the replacement for a preg_replace() use preg_replace_callback().

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer guys!
Actually I found another solution as well.

preg_replace_callback also works for this and I came up with this which also works:

```
$data = preg_replace_callback('/\[pagelink\](.*?)\[\/pagelink\]/is',function ($matches) { return '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?p='.$matches[1].'">'.( strstr($matches[1],'/') === false ? $matches[1] : str_replace('_',' ',str_replace('/','',strstr($matches[1],'/'))) ).'</a>'; },$data);
```

however your suggestions are great and very helpful!
Thanks!